# Run tests from a different source folder other than src

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I have an app that I scaffolded by using CRA. In my app, I have two folders within the src folder. The first folder contains the generic components (like Buttons, Modals among other custom elements). The second folder contains the business related components but they use generic components as well.

I have now started writing unit tests for my business related components. When I generate the code coverage numbers, I am realizing that the generic components are also taken into consideration when the code coverage is taken into consideration.

I would somehow like my tests to run from the Business related component folder onwards instead of the src folder.

Is there something that I can do in this regard, without ejecting from CRA ?

Comment: If your aim is to get coverage for the correct files, why not set [`collectCoverageFrom`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#collectcoveragefrom-array) accordingly? That being said, why aren't the generic components also tested?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can I use relative paths to the src folder ? Thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks its worked. can you please answer this question as well, so I can mark it as the correct answer , please ?  Thanks